# Why am I getting an exception with a push involved with a shared pointer?

Tags: c++

How do I pass a smart pointer into this class so that it may be pushed into.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] that demonstrates what you want to do without anyone having to guess. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Edit your own question, not my answer. I will edit my answer once you provided a [mcve]. If you can also provide an example of the error on https://godbolt.org that would be wonderful.

Comment: Well, the behavior desired was for a push to work which has been offered and did work.  However, any other problems were appreciated by those that are better.

Comment: How should this be stated, related problems?

Comment: The problem was the push, but this may have only been one symptom.

Comment: Oh, it needed to be in the question, all this, and it would be ok?

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
auto alltransactions(atrans);
```

Declares a new variable named `alltransactions`, which has the same name as your member.

Your constructor should use member init list to ensure your member are initialized correctly:

```
struct my_class {
    my_class(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<cl_order>> atrans) : transactions(atrans) {}

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<cl_order>> transactions;
};
```